# I'm not sure why my variance function returns 0.0000 0.0000

Tags: c, memory

My program runs, but my output should print the variance and the average. I was told as my input array sizes get larger and larger my average should get closer to 5000 and my variance should approach 8333333... Yet I am getting 0 for both. The only thing I can think of is that I'm filling my mydata array/memoryblock incorrectly, but I don't know another way to do it if not the way I have written.

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc, calloc, realloc, free
#include <math.h> //pow

double average_variance(int data[], int numbers, double* varp){
    
    double sum = 0;
    //sum of array
    for(int i=0; i < numbers; i++){
        sum += data[i];
    }
    double average = sum/numbers;

    double squaresum = 0;
    //sum of squares
    for(int i=0; i < numbers; i++){
        squaresum += pow(data[i], 2);
    }

    //"hack" to return two values by using a pointer; otherwise you can't return two values in a function
    double variance = ((squaresum/numbers) - pow(average, 2));
    *varp = variance;
    
    return average;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int* mydata = NULL;
    int arraysize;
    
    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Enter array size (0 to end): "); scanf("%d", &arraysize);
        
        if (arraysize == 0)
        break;
        
        // 1. Add code to allocate memory and assign to the mydata // pointer. If mydata is already allocated, use realloc ...
        
if(arraysize != 0)
        {   
            //used calloc because in the next if statement I needed to see if values were stored in it or not 
            mydata = calloc(arraysize, sizeof(int));
            if (mydata == NULL) {return -1;}
            
            //if mydata array is already allocated use realloc to make a new memory block 
            if(mydata != 0)
            {
                mydata = realloc(mydata, arraysize * sizeof(int));
                if (mydata == NULL) {return -1;}
            }

        }
    
        // 2. Add code to put random numbers in the array
        for(; mydata < &mydata[-1]; mydata++)
        {
            int randnum = random() % 10000;
            mydata = &randnum;
        }
        
        
        //included
        double variance;
        double avg = average_variance(mydata, arraysize, &variance);
        printf("average = %f variance = %f\n", avg, variance);
    }
    free(mydata);
```

Comment: `for(; mydata < &mydata[-1]; mydata++)` That is a very weird line. You should not modify your pointer as you need it to free the memory later. Also what is this condition even supposed to mean? As you assign the address of local variable `randnum` to `mydata`  you increment to point behind that variable. You should check your text book how to access elements in an array.

Answer (score 2):

The array initialization code is broken:

```
        for(; mydata < &mydata[-1]; mydata++)
        {
            int randnum = random() % 10000;
            mydata = &randnum;
        }
```

Errors:

- `mydata[-1]` is not the last element of `mydata` (a'la Python) but it is an element just *before* the array. This element does not exist, Undefined Behavior is invoked.
- the `mydata` is moved during the initiazation to a local variable in the loop. There is no hope for this construct to work.

Just do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
            mydata[i] = random() % 10000;
```

Moreover, the allocation code is needlessly convoluted. Just replace:

```
if(arraysize != 0)
        {   
            //used calloc because in the next if statement I needed to see if values were stored in it or not 
            mydata = calloc(arraysize, sizeof(int));
            if (mydata == NULL) {return -1;}
            
            //if mydata array is already allocated use realloc to make a new memory block 
            if(mydata != 0)
            {
                mydata = realloc(mydata, arraysize * sizeof(int));
                if (mydata == NULL) {return -1;}
            }

        }
```

with:

```
    mydata = realloc(mydata, arraysize * sizeof *mydata);
    if (!mydata) return -1;
```

Comment: I was using the syntax this YouTube video used at 8:25 in the for loop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw1qsMieK5c&t=429s I'm not sure what I did differently than him, but thank you!

Comment: @Zoxze, `realloc` accepts `NULL` as the first argument. In sucha case it works like `malloc()`. Therefore there is no need to use a special case with `calloc/malloc`.

Comment: @Zoxze, prefer the "more traditional" way described a few moments later in https://youtu.be/mw1qsMieK5c?t=507

Comment: @Zoxze what is show in it the youtube video you mentioned is very different from what _you_  are doing.